# RegEx Matching all occurences of "//" but not when part of "http://"

Tags: php, regex

I have a string containing HTML elements and I would like to convert all occurrences of "//" to "http://" where "//" is not already part of "http://"

How can I achieve this with a regex?

As example I have URLs like:

```
//example.net
```

And I want to convert them to

```
http://example.net
```

Comment: `if strpos() === 0`

Comment: Look at negative lookaheads. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html https://regex101.com/r/rV6uG3/1

Comment: which programming language are you using? javascript regex doesn't have negative lookbehind

Comment: @Can It's tagged as PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using PHP you are safe to use this one with a negative look-behind:

```
/(?<!http:|https:)\/\//
```

[Demo](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/gLo)

Please note, that look-behinds are not working in JavaScript.
This one also takes "https://" into account

Answer (score 3):

You need negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!http:)\/\/
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yF5hK2/1).

Comment: thanks for your input, what would happen if I have "https://" in my string

Comment: @Dasj If you want a single regex for both the cases you can use `(?<!https?:)\/\/`